# How to take mysql database Backup in MAC os via command prompt

Tags: mysql, centos

i am using MAC os and trying to get the mysql database backup with the following command but its giving database error:

mysqldump -u root -proot syslog > syslog.sql

while running this command showing this error:
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-u root -p syslog > syslog.sql' at line 1

Answer (score 2):

You appear to be running `mysqldump` from within the `mysql` interpreter. Instead, you need to run it from your shell prompt.